# curl download with username and password in varible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, curl

Hi I am writing a auto script in test.sh , attempting to download a file. It works fine when I use all hard code string.  But it does not work with variables. Belong are my code example:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="admin"
PWD="adminpass"


curl -v -k  -u ${USER}:${PWD} ${NEXUS_URL}/${SP1}/60/${SP1}-60.zip --output ${SP1}-60.zip
```

Above code not working not able to download my file, but if I put it as :

```
curl -v -k  -u "admin":"adminpass" ${NEXUS_URL}/${SP1}/60/${SP1}-60.zip 
--output ${SP1}-60.zip
```

Then it works. So how do I get the variable credential working with this curl command?
Thanks

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Don't use `PWD` as a variable name, it is special to the shell and contains the present working directory. In general, prefer lowercase variable names, exactly to reduce the probability of name clashes like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

The parameter expansion will not include the double quotes. You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER='"'admin'"'     #single quote, double quote, single quote
PASS='"'adminpass'"'

curl -v -k  -u ${USER}:${PASS} ${NEXUS_URL}/${SP1}/60/${SP1}-60.zip
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively, you can create a .netrc file and use curl -n as follows:

Documentation from https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-netrc.html

1. Create .netrc containing the following and place it in your home directory.

   ```
   machine http://something.com
   login admin
   password adminpass
   ```
2. Run the command

   ```
   curl -n -k --output ${SP1}-60.zip
   ```

   curl will automatically look for the .netrc file. You can also specify the file path with `curl --netrc-file <netrc_file_path>`